# Store Array of custom Objects Swift

Tags: arrays, object, swift, save

I have a class called "Entry".

in there I have different variables like Int, NSDate and Float.

I have an array "listData" which consist of these elements.

This "listData" is filling a TableView. How do I store and read this array? How would an implementation look like?

I have tried to iterate through the array and saving the single elements of the "Entry" class to put it back together while loading. It does not seem to work properly.

Here is some of my code:

My Entry Class:

```
import Foundation

class Entry  {

let number      : Int
let date        : NSDate
let mileage     : Int
let trip        : Float
let speed       : Float
let consumption : Float

init(number: Int, date: NSDate, mileage: Int, trip: Float, speed: Float, consumption: Float) {


    self.number         = number
    self.date           = date
    self.mileage        = mileage
    self.trip           = trip
    self.speed          = speed
    self.consumption    = consumption
    }
}
```

Then I have a global variable for the array:

```
var listData = [Entry]()
```

On a second ViewController I have declared some Variables which take the input of Textfield, to save them to a new "Entry" Object, which will then be appended to the listData Array:

```
listData.append(Entry(number: number_pass, date: date_pass, mileage: mileage_pass, trip: trip_pass, speed: speed_pass, consumption: consumption_pass))
```

Everything else I have in code is just setting up and managing the Tableviews.

Is there a way to use UserDefaults? Or do I have to use CoreData?

Hope You can help!
Cheers, Niklas

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use NSUserDefaults, you can use Core Data. This first class is just for make things easier:

```
class CoreDataHelper: NSObject {

    class func insertManagedObject(className: String, moc: NSManagedObjectContext) ->AnyObject {
        let managedObject: NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(className, inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! NSManagedObject
        return managedObject
    }

    class func fetchEntities(className: String, withPredicate predicate: NSPredicate?, moc: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSArray {
        let request: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        let entityDescription: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(className, inManagedObjectContext: moc)!

        request.entity = entityDescription

        if predicate != nil {
            request.predicate = predicate!
        }

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        let items: NSArray = moc.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
        return items
     }

}
```

And in your ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: NSTableView!

// Your datastore
private var myArray = [Entry]()

// ManagedObjectContext
lazy var moc: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let appi = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    if let moc = appi.managedObjectContext {
        return moc
    } else {
        return nil
    }
    }()

func reloadTableView(sender: AnyObject) {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entry")

    // Just an example of sort descriptor
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]

    var anyerror: NSError?

    let fetchedEntries = moc?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &anyerror)

    if fetchedEntries == nil {
        println("Error fetching: \(anyerror)")
        return
    }

    myArray = fetchedEntries as! [Entry]

    myTableView.reloadData()
}

// Life cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    reloadTableView(self)

}
```

Comment: Do I have to check the "Use CoreData" checkbox before creating a project? Or will this work without? Since I did not check it when I was creating the project

Comment: Yes, and then you have to make Entity for your class. Im not sure how easy it is to add Core Data Model your existing project, because Xcode provides some function already when you check the box.

Comment: Thank you! I will try out building it new with CoreData enabled.

Comment: Your code is throwing an error :/  let appi = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate "Use of unresolved Identifier 'NSApplication'"

Comment: Im not sure why, because for me that works...My example is for OS X, do you also use Cocoa?

Comment: I'm using the most recent Xcode & Swift. This is going to be an iOS application.

Comment: Ok, my example was for OS X app, and I don't know much iOS. But I think it might work if you change that my example like that:

let appi = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

Comment: No, I am not using it. If I have to I will.

Comment: Changing it to UIApplication... Will throw an error like this: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'Entry''

Comment: Not sure why is that. Here is good Core Data tutorial [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift)

Comment: Thank you! I will test this and write back as soon as confirmed working!:)